# Undefined Reference, Error Linking Plplot with GFortran

Tags: linker, fortran, linker-errors, gfortran

I tried to compile the following Fortran code found at
http://techlogbook.wordpress.com/200...-kubuntu-8-04/

```
program testplplot2d
use plplot
implicit none
real(plflt),dimension(6) :: x,y
real(plflt)::xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax
x=(/1,2,3,4,5,6/)
y=x**2
write(*,*) y
call plinit()
xmin=1.0
xmax=6.0
ymin=1.0
ymax=40.0
call plcol0(1)
call plenv(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,0,0)
call pllab('X','Y','Test 1D plot')
call plpoin(x,y,9)
call plline(x,y)
y=x**3
call plpoin(x,y,9)
call plline(x,y)
call plend()

end program testplplot2d
```

I used the following command in my attempt to compile the program:

```
gfortran -I/usr/lib/fortran/modules/plplot testplot2d.f90 -o testplot2d
```

However I received the a linking error message detailed below:

```
/tmp/cckSqEg4.o: In function `MAIN__':
testplot2d.f90:(.text+0x10c): undefined reference to `plinit_'
testplot2d.f90:(.text+0x154): undefined reference to `plcol0_'
testplot2d.f90:(.text+0x181): undefined reference to `plenv_'
testplot2d.f90:(.text+0x1a6): undefined reference to `__plplotp_MOD_pllab'
testplot2d.f90:(.text+0x248): undefined reference to `__plplot_MOD_plpoin'
testplot2d.f90:(.text+0x2e5): undefined reference to `__plplot_MOD_plline'
testplot2d.f90:(.text+0x3c6): undefined reference to `__plplot_MOD_plpoin'
testplot2d.f90:(.text+0x463): undefined reference to `__plplot_MOD_plline'
testplot2d.f90:(.text+0x46d): undefined reference to `plend_'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What should I do to correct this problem? (I read the man pages for gfortran, and I believe I am using the correct option for linking against a library.)

Comment: Your link to the source is broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this on the ubuntuforums as well.  User gmargo [posted](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10209361&postcount=4) the following solution:

Install the libplplot-dev package and then compile with this command line:

```
gfortran testplot2d.f90 -o testplot2d $(pkg-config --cflags --libs plplotd-f95)
```

Thank you @belisarius and @High-Performance-Mark for your efforts.

Answer (score 2):

The error messages that you show us are generated by the linker, not the compiler.  I don't know gfortran so what follows may be wide of the mark

-I generally (on the Linux and Unix compilers I am familiar with) identifies a directory which contains files to be included in compilation, rather than when linking.  For Fortran the `.mod` files created when you compile a module have to be included during compilation.

Since you are not getting error messages telling you that the module you `USE` is not found, you can work on the basis that it is being found where you tell the compiler to look.

The Linux compilers I am familiar with use the -L flag, a directory, and an abbreviated form of the library name to identify libraries to be linked.  In your case I would have expected to see something like:

```
-L/path/to/installed/lib/files -lplplot
```

included in your compilation statement.  How you tell gfortran to include the library at link time I do not know, but I do not see anything in your compilation statement that does tell gfortran what libraries to link.

Comment: According to the man pages it should work:
<pre><code>   
-Idir
    These affect interpretation of the "INCLUDE" directive (as well as of the "#include" directive of the cpp preprocessor).

    Also note that the general behavior of -I and "INCLUDE" is pretty much the same as of -I with "#include" in the cpp preprocessor, with regard to looking for header.gcc files and other such things.

    This path is also used to search for .mod files when previously compiled modules are required by a "USE" statement. 
</code></pre>

Comment: @rmtatum: maybe it should work, but it doesn't.  I've now read some of the man page for gcc and do not believe that you are providing the correct link statement in your compilation command.  If you have only read the man pages for gfortran you have missed a lot of the story -- they only document what gfortran provides over and above the rest of gcc.  Keep reading.

Comment: Using the command you suggested (which I tried prior to reading your post), the following error is produced:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lplplot
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 0):

You have missing external references.

[The page from where you got the code](http://techlogbook.wordpress.com/2009/09/18/using-plplot-from-fortran-in-kubuntu-8-04/) starts:

**I installed libplplot from Kubuntu Adept package manager, and chose “libplplot-fortran9″ package.**

*I guess you should do the same.*

Comment: Thanks for stating the obvious, but I already had the library installed.

Comment: @rmtatum Next time try to provide all the relevant information. So you'll not get _obvious_ suggestions